# Transforming a string_view in-place

Tags: c++, c++20, string-view, toupper, tolower

`std::transform`, as of C++20, is declared `constexpr.` I have a bunch of string utility functions that take `std::string` arguments, but a lot of the usage ends up just passing in small, short, character literal sequences at compile-time. I thought I would leverage this fact and declare versions that are `constexpr` and take `std::string_view`s instead of creating temporary `std::string` variables just to throw them away...

ORIGINAL `STD::STRING` VERSION:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] std::string ToUpperCase(std::string string) noexcept {
    std::transform(string.begin(), string.end(), string.begin(), [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c, std::locale("")); });
    return string;
}
```

NEW `STD::STRING_VIEW` VERSION:

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] constexpr std::string_view ToUpperCase(std::string_view stringview) noexcept {
    std::transform(stringview.begin(), stringview.end(), stringview.begin(), [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c, std::locale("")); });
    return stringview;
}
```

But MSVC complains:

```
error C3892: '_UDest': you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

Is there a way to call `std::transform` with a `std::string_view` and put it back into the `std::string_view` or am I going to have to create a local string and return that, thereby defeating the purpose of using `std::string_view` in the first place?

```cpp
[[nodiscard]] constexpr std::string ToUpperCase(std::string_view stringview) noexcept {
    std::string copy{stringview};
    std::transform(stringview.begin(), stringview.end(), copy.begin(), [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c, std::locale("")); });
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: A `string_view` is an immutable view into a sequence of characters. It looks but doesn't touch. That's the whole reason it doesn't need to copy anything to form a view of a `const char[]` C-style string literal.

Comment: No way to avoid copying because `string_view` only gives const access - and it is good. How would you want to avoid copying in `auto upper = ToUpperCase("foo");`?

Comment: `std::string_view` refers to a constant contiguous sequence. Why not try `std::span<char>`?

Comment: @ecatmur - because it would have different semantics: in-place modification.

Comment: @Eugene which is what it sounds like he wants to me. He specifically asks at the end if there is a way to modify it in place.

Comment: Returning a `string_view` (which is non-owning) is already a dangling reference bug, nevermind what the guts of the function do.

Answer (score 4):

As said in one comment, `span` is a better vocabulary type for this because individual elements can be modified, giving a sort of mutable string view (`msv`).
Also, I wouldn't make it `nodiscard`, because it can be useful even without assigning the result:

```
#include<algorithm>  // for std::transform
#include<cassert>
#include<locale>  // for std::to_upper
#include<string_view>
#include<span>

constexpr auto ToUpperCase(std::span<char> msv) noexcept {
    std::transform(msv.begin(), msv.end(), msv.begin(), [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c); });
    return msv;
}

int main() {
    auto a = std::string{"compiler"};
    auto&& tmp = ToUpperCase(a);
    auto b = std::string{tmp.begin(), tmp.end()};
    assert( a == "COMPILER");
    assert( b == "COMPILER");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zPr968PYr

---

Somewhat departing from your original aim...
I think this is more elegant, although subject to bloating and ugly compilation errors.
It has the same effect in the cases provided.

Also I don't like the design of `span` (or `string_view` for that matter)

(Exercise: add Concepts)

```
template<class StringRange>
constexpr StringRange&& ToUpperCase(StringRange&& stringview) noexcept {
    std::transform(stringview.begin(), stringview.end(), stringview.begin(),
        [](unsigned char c) -> unsigned char { return std::toupper(c); });
    return std::forward<StringRange>(stringview);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/e9aWKMerE

I find myself using this idiom quite a bit lately.

Answer (score 2):

You can't in-place transform a `std::string_view` - what if it has been constructed from `char const*`?

> a lot of the usage ends up just passing in small, short, character literal sequences at compile-time.

...but you can lift string literals to the type level

```
namespace impl {
    template<std::size_t n> struct Str {
        std::array<char, n> raw{};
        constexpr Str(char const (&src)[n + 1]) { std::copy_n(src, n, raw.begin()); }
    };
    template<std::size_t n> Str(char const (&)[n]) -> Str<n - 1>;
}
template<char... cs> struct Str { static char constexpr value[]{cs..., '\0'}; };
template<impl::Str s>
auto constexpr str_v = []<std::size_t... is>(std::index_sequence<is...>) {
    return Str<s.raw[is]...>{};
}(std::make_index_sequence<s.raw.size()>{});
```

...and add a special case. In general, this hack can be avoided with range/tuple polymorphic algorithms.

```
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto ToUpperCase(auto str) {
    for (auto&& c: str) c = ConstexprToUpper(c); // std::toupper doesn't seem constexpr
    return str;
}
template<char... cs> [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto ToUpperCase(Str<cs...>) {
    return Str<ConstexprToUpper(cs)...>{};
}
```

So, to use that transformation optimized for character literal sequences, now write `ToUpperCase(str_v<"abc">)` instead of `ToUpperCase("abc"sv)`. If you always want `string_view` as output, return `std::string_view{Str<ConstexprToUpper(cs)...>::value}` in that overload.

Comment: Could you explain what you have achieved? Usage example of the 2 overloads of `ToUpperCase()` and in which way they are better than the straightforward implementation OP showed?

Comment: @Eugene yes: my version provides "way to call std::transform with a std::string_view and put it back into the std::string_view" instead of "create a local string and return that, thereby defeating the purpose of using std::string_view in the first place".

Comment: Could you add an example of doing it in your answer? Also, are you creating the  uppercase of string literals at compile time?

Comment: @Eugene I've edited my answer to show the usage. Yes, the transformation happens at compile time.

Comment: Thank you, +1 since it shows advanced techniques, although I would not use this in production.